# getting PS old gen size at runtime

Tags: java, heap-memory

In my java code I can get the Heap free memory amount with:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory()
```

I would like to get instead the amount of "PS Old Gen" memory usage, like shown for example by jConsole in Memory tab, chart: Memory Pool "PS Old Gen".

How can I do, using java code?

Thank you.